# why resque-web is not showing all running resque workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

question in the title

i can see resque workers in htop: `resque-1.15.0: Processing low since 1317112029` but they don't show up in resque-web

anyone had this issue?

Comment: Restart the workers.  They're supposed to register themselves in redis when they start up. Maybe something failed when they tried to do that? Have never seen this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by upgrading to resque 1.19

Answer (score 0):

Check your namespace in resque-web. If you are using redis-namespace in your resque installation, and the namespace doesn't match that of the worker, you won't see those workers in resque-web

Comment: there are no problems with namespace, i do see some other workers but not the long-running